# Derivative of $|S|$ or $\text{sign}(S)$ with respect to $S$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

This is related to another question I have asked but I'm interested in the derivative of $|S|$ with respect to $S$. Here, $S$ is a symmetric, non-singular matrix and $|S|$ is the absolute value function i.e. Let $S = QDQ^T$ be an eigenvalue decomposition of $S$. Then we define $|S| = Q|D|Q^T$ as the matrix with the same eigenvectors as $S$ but whose eigenvalues are the absolute values of the respective eigenvalues of $S$.

A related problem is the derivative of $\text{sign}(S)$ with respect to $S$. Where, this time, $\text{sign}(S) = Q \text{sign}(D)Q^T$ has eigenvalues equal to the sign of the respective eigenvalues of $S$. The relation comes from the fact that $|S| = S\text{sign}(S) = \text{sign}(S)S$.

Since $S$ has no zero eigenvalues, I'd like to think the derivative of $|S|$ and $\text{sign}(S)$ exist but I'm struggling to see how to move forwards.

Comment: The standard and prudent approach would be to re-write this using Polar Decomposition which is unique for invertible matrices.  Your 'sign(S)' is the orthogonal $U$ and your |S| is the $P$ as in $S=UP$.

Comment: For any symmetric $S$ with non-zero eigenvalues, $\operatorname{sign}$ is constant in some neighborhood of $S$, which means that the derivative of $\operatorname{sign}$ must be zero at $S$.